Lists in pandas dataframe cells
If we have a (part of a bigger) dataframe that shows what states individuals (rows) visited in a trip:
df = pd.DataFrame({'states_visited': [['NY', 'CA'], 'CA', 'CA']}, index = ['John', 'Mary', 'Joe'])

        states_visited
John    [NY, CA]
Mary    CA
Joe     CA

Because the states_visited column has values of type list, we can't use usual pandas methods like:
df['states_visited'].unique()

to get the expected outcome of: [[NY, CA] , CA] which is what we need for example if we want to know what states were visited together (NY and CA) and which states were visited separately (CA).
Instead, we get TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
Similarly, we can't do df['states_visited'].str.contains('NY') to know who visited NY in his/her trip (it will return NaN for John). To achieve this, we have to go through the hoop of something like:
df['states_visited'].explode()
                 .dropna()
                 .str.contains('NY')
                 .groupby(level=0).any()
                 .astype(float)
                )

So, if pandas does not like nested data, what is the proper way of having list-like values in a pandas dataframe/series (not simple dictionaries because this example data is a part of a bigger dataframe)?

Why .astype(float)? Everything else there makes sense except that.

@wjandrea I had it in the code since the actual column contains NaNs and but, yes, not applicable in this excerpt of the dataframe.

Oh, what's the end goal of that snippet? I thought it was to make a mask (boolean selector).

@wjandrea there is no specific single goal. It just happens that several pandas methods/attributes like .unique() that I use all the time do not work on series containing list-type values, which I have in my datasets all the time. I'm wondering how else I can have list-like values in a series while still being able to use such methods. Like in my example above, I don't know how else the states_visited column can be constructed for df['states_visited'].unique() to return [[NY, CA] , CA]. Is it a shortcoming in pandas or is there a good reason it does not work on lists?

You could make each row contain only one state, and have multiple rows for people who've been to multiple states.
John NY
John CA
Mary CA
Joe CA

This should let you easily all unique states and find out who visited a given state.
If this is part of a bigger dataframe with many other columns, you might not want to duplicate all of them when you switch to multiple rows per person. So you might have to break it up into smaller dataframes that can be joined together when needed (think relational database normalization).
Another option is to store the list as a string (e.g. "NY,CA"), which might let you do some of the things you want, but will take some parsing.

No, that would exponentially increase the dataframe size. Imagine multiple list columns with long lists

@Saeed They talked about that: "So you might have to break it up into smaller dataframes that can be joined together when needed"

converting to string is something I've done before to be able to use, for example, str.contains() on the column but then for example to get the number of items in the original list, I'll have to split the string equivalents by ',' which recreates them as list. So, while this works, it's more like a work-around than a fundamental solution.

There is no need to 'explode' the DF column. You can just access the states_visited directly. The column is of object type with both List and String. See the examples you mention below. More complex conditions can be constructed as required.
df = pd.DataFrame({'states_visited': [['NY', 'CA'], 'CA', 'CA']}, index = ['John', 'Mary', 'Joe'])
#show the rows with multiple states
print(df[df['states_visited'].map(lambda x: isinstance(x,list))])

#show the rows with single states
print(df[df['states_visited'].map(lambda x: not isinstance(x,list))])

#show just the states which were uniquely visited
print(set(df[df['states_visited'].map(lambda x: not isinstance(x,list))]['states_visited'].to_list()))

#show the rows containing NY
print(df[df['states_visited'].map(lambda x: 'NY' in x)])

gives:
     states_visited
John       [NY, CA]

     states_visited
Mary             CA
Joe              CA

{'CA'}

     states_visited
John       [NY, CA]

